# C#/ Visual studio 2019 || windows form autoscroll flickering

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a Windows Form that shows display data from data a table. Every thing is working fine until I start scrolling in the Form using the auto scroll property.

I don't know why that's happening. I hope someone can help me.

```
        private void allShowsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Load All the Shows from the database
            DataTable dt = accesse.LoadAllShows();

            // Create the allShows From
            Form allShows = new Form();

            // Create the Controls for the AllShows form.
            PictureBox[] pic = new PictureBox[dt.Rows.Count];
            Label[] showName = new Label[dt.Rows.Count], season = new Label[dt.Rows.Count], eps = new Label[dt.Rows.Count], typ = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];
            TextBox[] txtShowName = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count], txtSeason = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count], txtEps = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count], txtTyp = new TextBox[dt.Rows.Count];

            // AllShows Form properties
            allShows.BackColor = Color.White;
            allShows.Font = new Font("Calibri", 14f, FontStyle.Regular);
            allShows.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            allShows.Size = new Size(1050, 700);
            allShows.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            allShows.AutoScroll = true;
            allShows.AutoScrollMargin = new Size(0, 18);
            

            // Variables
            int y = 325; // the distens bettwen the controls on the Y and X.
            bool xTurn = false; // the axies turn.
            int yTurnNum = 0; // the y turn number.

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                // PictureBox Poster Properties
                pic[i] = new PictureBox();
                pic[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pic[i].Size = new Size(162, 288);
                pic[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pic[i].Image = Image.FromFile(dt.Rows[i][4].ToString());

                // Label showName Properties
                showName[i] = new Label();
                showName[i].Text = "Show Name: " + dt.Rows[i][0];
                showName[i].AutoSize = true;

                // Label Season Properties
                season[i] = new Label();
                season[i].Text = "Season: " + dt.Rows[i][1];
                season[i].AutoSize = true;

                // Label Eps Properties
                eps[i] = new Label();
                eps[i].Text = "Episodes: " + dt.Rows[i][2];
                eps[i].AutoSize = true;

                // Label Typ Properties
                typ[i] = new Label();
                typ[i].Text = "Typ: " + dt.Rows[i][3];
                typ[i].AutoSize = true;

                if (xTurn)
                {
                    // Sitting the location of the controls on the X turn
                    pic[i].Location = new Point(515, pic[i - 1].Location.Y);
                    showName[i].Location = new Point(687, showName[i - 1].Location.Y);
                    season[i].Location = new Point(687, season[i - 1].Location.Y);
                    eps[i].Location = new Point(687, eps[i - 1].Location.Y);
                    typ[i].Location = new Point(687, typ[i - 1].Location.Y);

                    xTurn = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sitting the location of the controls on the Y turn
                    pic[i].Location = new Point(15, 15 + (yTurnNum * y));
                    showName[i].Location = new Point(187, 20 + (yTurnNum * y));
                    season[i].Location = new Point(187, 55 + (yTurnNum * y));
                    eps[i].Location = new Point(187, 90 + (yTurnNum * y));
                    typ[i].Location = new Point(187, 125 + (yTurnNum * y));

                    yTurnNum += 1;
                    xTurn = true;
                }

                
                allShows.Controls.Add(pic[i]);
                allShows.Controls.Add(showName[i]);
                allShows.Controls.Add(season[i]);
                allShows.Controls.Add(eps[i]);
                allShows.Controls.Add(typ[i]);

            }

            

            allShows.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tools.ShowErrorMessageBox(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

I hope this gif will help you to understand what is happening.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHFnW.gif)

Comment: Why are you using AutoScrollMargin?

Comment: PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage is a convenience, but not one you want if smooth scrolling is important.  Scale the image yourself, favor 32bppArgb for the pixel format.

Comment: @viveknuna I am using AutoscrollMargin to add a little space to the Form in the down side of it when the user scroll all the way down.